Green function of an elliptic operator
Let $L$ be an elliptic operator on $\Bbb C$ with
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Img}{Im}
L^{-1}f(z)=\int_{\Bbb {C}}K_1(|z-w|^2)f(w) e^{i\cdot\Img\langle z,\overline{w}\rangle} \, dw
$$ where $K_1$ is the modified Bessel function.
I want to define the kernel Poisson to the Dirichlet problem $Lu=0 $ on the unit Ball $B$ of $\Bbb C$ with $u=f$ on the sphere $S$.
How can I do that?
Thank you in advance.

Related, but dealing with the construction of fundamental solution instead of the construction of the Green function. Remember that once you have a fundamental solution, you can construct a Green function for a given domain if you know an entire solution for the same operator

@DanieleTampieri Can you explain in more detail the last part?

@GiorgioMetafune, assuming that we know a fundamental solution of the elliptic operator $L$, i.e. a solution of the non homogeneous equation $$ L E(x-y) = \delta (x-y),$$ if moreover we know an "entire solution" of the homogeneous one, i.e. a solution of the following equation $$ L G (x,y)=0$$ such that $$ E(x-y) =G(x,y)\quad x\in \partial B,, y\in B^\circ,$$ where $B^\circ$ is the interior of $B$, then we know the Green function $\mathscr{G}(x,y)$. I apologise for the non-standard locution: when $L=\Delta$, $G$ is an harmonic function respect to the $x$ variable.

Thank you for your response@Daniele Tampieri. In above we have $LK_1(|z-w|^2)=0$, but the Green function is not $G(z,w)=K_1(|z-w|^2)$, the Green function is the kernel of the operator $L^{-1}$. In our case $G(z,w)=K_1(|z-w|^2)e^{i Imz.\overline{w}}$

Ryo, am I missing something? $G(z,w)$ does not vanish on $\partial B$ while a Green function should vanish on the boundary of the domain associated to it: $G(z,w)$ seems more a fundamental solution.

@DanieleTampieri. in the above case, how the Poisson Kernel is defined?

Ryo, in the above case, the Green function is defined as $$\mathscr G(x,y)= E(x-y) - G(x,y)$$ and the Poisson kernel is given by $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{n}} \mathscr G(x, y))$$ where $\hat{n}$ is the inner normal vector to the boundary of the associated domain, but at this point I should explain better, since I'm doing things remembering what happens for self-adjoint $L$'s and I am possibly doing some slips. I need a couple of days to arrange a nice answer.

Iin my case $G(z,w)=K_1(|z-w|^2)e^{i Imz.\overline{w}}$. So, $\mathscr G(x,y)= E(x-y) - G(x,y)=G(x,y/|y|)-G(x,y)$. Is it true. @DanieleTampieri

The notation and terminology here is a bit confusing. I think that the starting point to match the OP's question to Daniele's discussion is the fundamental solution $E(z-w) \text{ "=" } K_1(|z-w|^2) e^{i\operatorname{Im} z\cdot\bar{w}}$, which already doesn't work because the rhs is not translation invariant, so one would have to write the lhs as $E(z,w)$. Next, the correct interior Dirichlet Green function is $\mathscr{G}(z,w) = E(z,w) - G(z,w)$, where the crucially necessary $G(z,w)$ is the unknown "entire solution". The "Poisson kernel" is then the differentiated $\mathscr{G}$.

@IgorKhavkine. Thank you for your help.

Since @IgorKhavkine has perfectly described what I meant, the only thing I can say is that the procedure is completely described in the first chapter of Carlo Miranda's Partial differential equations of elliptic type, 2nd rev. ed. Translated from the Italian by Zane C. Motteler. Ergebnisse der Mathematik und ihrer Grenzgebiete, Band 2, Berlin-Heidelberg-New York: Springer-Verlag pp. XII+370 (1970) MR0284700, Zbl 0198.14101 (beware, the notation is old fashioned).

My last remark is that the reformulation of the problem in terms of the "entire solution" or the interior Dirichlet Green function leaves the OP none the wiser, as both reformulations are equally hard and are at least as hard if not harder than finding the desired "Poisson kernel".

Thank you@ Daniele Tampieri.

I can't find it
